# A question on the standard topology of $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: general-topology

Given a countable union of sets in $\mathbb{R}$ such that $\cup A_i = \mathbb{R}$, must at least one of them be dense in some open interval of $\mathbb{R}$? And, if the answer is yes, can anyone tell how I can prove it?
Thanks.

**ps:** This is a correction of a question I have asked before which was not written correctly. I apologize.

Comment: This is just Baire's theorem....

Comment: If you know measure theory and have trouble remembering Baire's theorem like I do, then there's a theorem to the effect that "statements about nowhere dense sets are analogous to statements about measure zero sets". A countable union of measure zero sets has measure zero, and analogously a countable union of nowhere dense sets is nowhere dense.

Comment: @ZachL. You mean "meager" instead of "nowhere dense".

Answer (score 3):

This is an immediate corollary from Baire's category theorem. In a complete metric space a countable union of nowhere dense sets is itself a nowhere dense set.

Since $\mathbb R$ is a complete metric space, it is not the countable union of nowhere dense sets, and so at least one of the sets must be dense somewhere.

Comment: Isn't $\mathbb{Q}$ a countable union of nowhere dense sets which is not itself nowhere dense?

Comment: Yes, but there's no problem with that! $\mathbb{Q}$ is "not as dense" as $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @ArthurFischer. Good point. Baire requires completeness. And $\mathbb{Q}$ is not completely metrizable.

Comment: @ThomasE.  In Asaf's otherwise good answer he states, "Countable union of nowhere dense sets, is itself nowhere dense."  I am attempting to draw his attention to this oversight; this is something I know Asaf knows, but we all have those moments -- heck I used a hedgehog space of uncountable spininess as a "simple" example of a non-separable metric space earlier today.

Comment: @Arthur: My advisor was 20 minutes early and I haven't had the time to edit, although I knew that some editing was in order. I'll get home in a couple of hours and fix everything... :-)

Comment: @Thomas: Yes, you and Arthur are both correct. My advisor was early and I hit "submit answer" without thinking too much. I corrected the minor inaccuracies.

Answer (score 2):

see: Baire's theorem in [Introductory Real Analysis](http://books.google.com/books?id=z8IaHgZ9PwQC&pg=PA61&dq=baire%27s%20theorem%20proof&hl=en&sa=X&ei=9LEXUdCNHcfptQaGsoHYBw&ved=0CEoQ6AEwBTgK#v=onepage&q=baire%27s%20theorem%20proof&f=false), P 61.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your helpfull answers. Bair theorem and it's proof was indeed the answer I was looking for. The exact statement of the theorem was indeed a bit different then what I wrote. It says that a complete metric space can not be represented as a countable union of nowhere dense sets.
Thanks again.
Shir